# Java garbage collector G1GC taking long for 'Object Copy' (Evacuation Pause)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm not a Java newby but I know only a tiny bit about garbage collection. Now I would like to change that with some practical experiences. My goal is a latency of under 0.3 seconds, or in extreme cases 0.5 is okay too.

I have an application with -Xmx50gb (-Xms50gb) and set the other following GC options:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -Xloggc:somewhere.gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

But now I'm occasionally having long pauses over 5sec due to garbage collections and that although there seems to be enough memory available. One reason I found:

```
[GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 42G->40G(48G), 5.9409662 secs]
```

Why is GCG1 still doing a "stop the world" for this? (Or at least I see that it stops my application at exactly this time) And why does it do such a negative cleanup if it is not really necessary as there is over 12% of the available RAM free. Also I thought that the default value for `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis` is 200 milliseconds, why is this value violated by a factor of 29 or even 50 (see below)?

Another reason for a delay was:

```
[GC pause (Metadata GC Threshold) (young) (initial-mark) 40G->39G(48G), 10.4667233 secs]
```

This will be probably solved [via this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25251388/194609) e.g. just increasing the metadata space `-XX:MetaspaceSize=100M`

BTW: Using JSE 1.8.0_91-b14

**Update:** detailed GC log of such an event

```
2016-08-12T09:20:31.589+0200: 1178.312: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 1178.312: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 3159, predicted base time: 1.52 ms, remaining time: 198.48 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
 1178.312: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 136 regions, survivors: 20 regions, predicted young region time: 1924.75 ms]
 1178.312: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 136 regions, survivors: 20 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 1926.27 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
 1185.330: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) attempt heap expansion, reason: recent GC overhead higher than threshold after GC, recent GC overhead: 21.83 %, threshold: 10.00 %, uncommitted: 0 bytes, calculated expansion amount: 0 bytes (20.00 %)]
 1185.330: [G1Ergonomics (Concurrent Cycles) do not request concurrent cycle initiation, reason: still doing mixed collections, occupancy: 42580574208 bytes, allocation request: 0 bytes, threshold: 23592960000 bytes (45.00 %), source: end of GC]
 1185.330: [G1Ergonomics (Mixed GCs) do not start mixed GCs, reason: reclaimable percentage not over threshold, candidate old regions: 1 regions, reclaimable: 3381416 bytes (0.01 %), threshold: 5.00 %]
, 7.0181903 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 6991.8 ms, GC Workers: 10]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 1178312.6, Avg: 1178312.8, Max: 1178312.9, Diff: 0.2]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 1.1, Avg: 1.5, Max: 2.3, Diff: 1.2, Sum: 15.0]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.3, Max: 1.3, Diff: 1.3, Sum: 3.4]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 2.1, Max: 5, Diff: 5, Sum: 21]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.4, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 1.7]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 6964.1, Avg: 6973.0, Max: 6989.5, Diff: 25.3, Sum: 69730.4]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 16.4, Max: 25.3, Diff: 25.3, Sum: 164.4]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 3.2, Max: 13, Diff: 12, Sum: 32]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.2]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 6991.5, Avg: 6991.6, Max: 6991.7, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 69915.5]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 1185304.3, Avg: 1185304.3, Max: 1185304.3, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.1 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.3 ms]
   [Other: 26.0 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 25.3 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
 [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.2 ms]
   [Eden: 2176.0M(2176.0M)->0.0B(2176.0M) Survivors: 320.0M->320.0M Heap: 40.6G(48.8G)->40.0G(48.8G)]
 [Times: user=0.55 sys=46.58, real=7.02 secs]
```

Read [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html) about it: Copying (Stop the World Event) - These are the stop the world pauses to evacuate or copy live objects to new unused regions. This can be done with young generation regions which are logged as [GC pause (young)]. Or both young and old generation regions which are logged as [GC Pause (mixed)].

Comment: have you read the official documentation?

Comment: Yes, sure. These ones http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html & http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc_tuning.html

Comment: Do you happen to explicitly call `System.gc()` from your application?

Comment: No, I do not call gc() explicitly.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to try with `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` in any case.

Comment: My application has many allocations which could be easily called "humongous allocations". Now I read that I should avoid those when using G1GC. What should I tune if I know that I have a base RAM usage of ~38g and just a few GB living objects on top? This this presentation http://presentations2015.s3.amazonaws.com/40_presentation.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is GCG1 still doing a "stop the world" for this?

Because G1 is not a *pauseless* collector, it is just a *low-pause* collector.

> Also I thought that the default value for -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis is 200 milliseconds, why is this value violated by a factor of 29 or even 50 (see below)?

It is, but it's just a goal, not a guarantee. Many things can cause it to fail to meet that goal. You got a fairly large heap, this makes things more difficult, i.e. failures are easier to provoke.

Anyway, the GC tuning journey starts with enabling verbose GC logging via

```
-Xloggc:<path to gc log file>
-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

Update: These options are for hotspot 8. 9 and later use [unified logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678557/how-to-list-syntax-and-available-tags-for-xlog) which has a different parameter format.

and then running the resulting log through [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) to get a general overview and then going back to [reading individual log entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7442742/1362755) (there are many answers/blog posts on this topic) to figure out what might be causing the worst behavior. Depending on the cause various remedies can be tried.

Some general understanding of how tracing garbage collectors work in general and G1 will be necessary to avoid cargo-culting.

> My application has many allocations which could be easily called "humongous allocations".

If that actually is the cause then current VMs have some [experimental options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065423/1362755) to reclaim them sooner.

> ```
>  [Object Copy (ms): Min: 6964.1, Avg: 6973.0, Max: 6989.5, Diff: 25.3, Sum: 69730.4]
>  [Times: user=0.55 sys=46.58, real=7.02 secs]
> ```

This means it spends most of the time in the kernel when doing something that should mostly consist of memory accesses and not system calls. So swap activity or [transparent huge pages](https://tobert.github.io/tldr/cassandra-java-huge-pages.html) are likely suspects.

Comment: Regarding PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy - what does it do? I mean the docs just say 'prints information about adaptive generation sizing'

Comment: Sorry, my fault: when making the comment about humongous allocations I forgot to say that these allocations are static and do not need to be allocated and they are likely to go to old generation regions. But maybe G1 still has a problem with them?

Comment: well, measuring instead of speculating may be more productive.

Comment: Thanks will study the now more detailed GC logs if this happens again

Comment: Updated the question with a detailed log of such an event. It looks like the copying took ~7sec! How can this be if there are 10 workers? Too many regions? Isn't this just `136/10` with max. size of 32MB each?

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'll immediately disable swapping. I think I forgot this for some servers and will let you know how it goes

Comment: We have this now enabled in production, will report in a few days. Also I found out about disabling 'zone reclaim mode', which could be interesting to investigate if this is still not fixed https://engineering.linkedin.com/performance/optimizing-linux-memory-management-low-latency-high-throughput-databases

Comment: After 2 weeks I do no longer see those GC related timeouts - thanks! Still seeing similar bigger delays (several seconds) ... anyway accepted your answer :)

Comment: The new shenandoah GC in the jvm seems promising

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the number of GC worker threads is 10. 
If the number of system CPUs is small, serious resource contention will occur, resulting in a significant increase in the time consumption of memory copy.